# Locations mapping looks off in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, csv

I want to upload a csv file with co-ordinates. The locations belong to USA. So I Upload a csv file to ArcMap and add XY data. The Projected Coordinate System is WGS_1984_World_Mercator. As soon as I add a base map, the locations are shown below continent of Africa. I tried changing the co-ordinate system. But not lucky ever. I am a beginner.

Anything I am overlooking?

Comment: I suspect your coordinates are latitudes and longitudes, are they within the range -180,180 for X and -90,90 for Y? In this case, you need to import them first as WGS84 (EPSG:4326), then you can _reproject_ your layer to World Mercator if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Null Island https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island.

Comment: Hi @FSimardGIS, yes the system is la-long. Example could be 39.731277 -75.128171.

Comment: Yes, these are indeed latitudes and longitudes. So you will have to choose WGS84 (EPSG:4326) as the coordinate system in the Add XY Data dialog. Make sure to select your Longitude field for the X value, and Latitude field for the Y value, and it should plot your points at the right place.